# Space and enter "click" on the input that's focused. How do I disable this behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In chrome and firefox (and maybe others), if you've got an input focused, pressing "space" and "enter" clicks them for you.  I'm making an HTML 5 game and I want to rewrite how space and enter reacts on focus and the default behavior is getting in my way.  Is there a way to turn this default behavior off in most browsers?

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmH5V/) demonstrating the problem.

```
<button>Button<button>
$("button").on("click", function(event) { alert("Clicked"); });
```

If you click on the button, it displays the alert which is good.  But if you press "space" or "enter" after you click it, it also alerts.  I want to prevent this behavior so that I can write my own without them interfering.

Comment: If you have your own handler for keyboard events, make sure they return `false` to prevent default action.

Comment: @Barmar oh, that may be the answer I'm looking for

Comment: @Barmar `return false;` is a little bit overkill though, since it will trigger an `event.stopPropagation()` as well. `event.preventDefault()` is what OP needs.

Comment: @Barmar Neither of your suggestions seem to be working for me.  See my update: http://jsfiddle.net/zmH5V/5/  Now when I press space, it fires both.

Comment: @Johan Your suggestion didn't work for me.  See http://jsfiddle.net/zmH5V/6/ When I press space, both get handlers get triggered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this by using [`event.detail`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.detail). That will return the amount of times the button has been clicked. If you press enter, this returns 0, since you clicked it 0 times, and if you click it via your mouse, it returns the amount of times you clicked the button.

To access `event.detail`, you need to access the original event object. This can be done via `event.originalEvent` in the jQuery event object. So, if you just put an if statement in your script:

```
if (event.originalEvent.detail != 0) {
    //your click event code
}
```

then it'll only run if you actually click the button via your mouse.

This will be much more accurate than checking if the button has `:focus`, since the button automatically gets focused when you click it, so doing that would disable the button after a single click.

Comment: I created a jsfiddle showing that this works even in firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/zmH5V/7/  I'm not sure how to use this information, though.  In my keydown handler, should I flip the if statement so it checks `== 0`?

Comment: @tieTYT if you want to add a handler for pressing the space or enter key you can simply make an `else` statement after this `if` statement, like I did [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zmH5V/8/). If you want to also trigger on other keypresses, then you can just use the keypress event handler like you would normally use it. The `event.detail` is [just for listing the amount of clicks, according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.detail#Notes), so you won't need it in a keypress (or keydown or keyup etc) event. PS: you closed your tag incorrectly. It should be `</button>`.

Answer (score 2):

Check if a button is active:

```
$("button").on("click", function(event) { alert("Clicked"); });

$(document).on('keydown', function(e){

    if($(document.activeElement).is('button') && 
                                         (e.keyCode === 13 || e.keyCode === 32)) 
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

You could also use jQuery's `:focus` selector, which should return the same element, `$(':focus').is('button')`.

http://jsfiddle.net/zmH5V/4/

Comment: fiddle doesnt work for me/ behaves like op-fiddle  on osx/chrome

Comment: @johnSmith I suggest that he replaces the click event for mouseup. The old code is still there.

Comment: haha didnt notice that, why does stackoverflow not include some js-fiddle-like stuff

Comment: For me, "space" is still firing the "click" alert.

Comment: @tieTYT FYI: There seems to be quite a lot of threads answering why preventDefault is beavhing differently in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

other option, is to blur the object right after clicking it:

```
<button id="mybutton" onclick="myFunction();this.blur();">button</button>
```

I find that solution easier to use, because it requires less code-lines, and gets the same results:
while the button is blured, it has no contact with the keyboards events, and that solves the problem.