# Doing something on second click with Snap.svg

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I am writing a basic code for an animation on click with Snap.svg. It looks like this:

```
var s = Snap(500, 500);

var circle = s.rect(100,100,100,100);

circle.click(function(){
  var width = circle.attr('width');
  var height = circle.attr('height');

  circle.animate({
    width: width/2,
    height :height/2
  }, 2000);


});
```

I make a rectangle in the top left corner of the container and animate it's width on a click. THEN, however, I want to do something different on the second click, return it to its original state for example.

I'd also be glad to learn how do you handle this second click in Javascript in general. 
For example: press this button once and the slide navigation opens. Tap it second time and the navigation dissappears.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using the [`event.detail`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.detail) property. In your case, that would be:

```
circle.click(function(e) {
  var width = circle.attr('width');
  var height = circle.attr('height');
  if (e.detail == 1) {
    circle.animate({
      width: width/2,
      height :height/2
    }, 2000);
  } else if (e.detail == 2) {
    circle.animate({ //example
      width:width,
      height:height
    }, 2000);
  }
});
```

There, the animation to change back to the original sizes plays when the user performs a double click (so 2x fast). If you basically want to toggle the element, instead of reverting it on doubleclick, you can simply check if the element has a `width` or `height` style other than its initial `width` or `height`:

```
circle.click(function(e) {
  var width = circle.attr('width');
  var height = circle.attr('height');
  if (parseInt(this.style.width) == parseInt(width) || !this.style.width) {
    circle.animate({
      width: width/2,
      height :height/2
    }, 2000);
  } else {
    circle.animate({ //example
      width:width,
      height:height
    }, 2000);
  }
});
```

Then the `if()` will return true when either the `width` attribute is equal to the `width` style, or when the `width` style is empty/not defined.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but when I click and have the rectangle shrink, I have to press the mouse button multiple times in order for it to work again and enlarge its size. Also, on the second click it becomes 2 times bigger, since it multiplies it with its original size - 100*2...

Comment: Please see my edits. I've added the code for a simple toggle mechanism. I've also fixed the reverting width and height, so that it reverts back to normal instead of growing to twice the original size.

Comment: I think an improvement to this would not to use the detail property but the data() method that belongs to Snaps Element prototype. You can place a flag in there within the event. eg. `if (this.data('clickCounter') == 0){ this.data('clickCounter', 1);} else { this.data('clickCounter',0); }`

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to store what state of the click.

There are many different ways to go about this, but I'll choose two:

Create a counter variable (say, `counter`) and increment it each time the `click` handler runs. Then, each time, to decide what to do,  see if the number is even or odd:

```
var counter = 0;
circle.click(function(){
  if(counter % 2 == 0){
    //action1
  }else{
    //action2
  }
  counter++;
});
```

Alternatively, you can use a Boolean that changes each time to keep track of which action to perform.

```
var flag = true;
circle.click(function(){
  if(flag){
    //action1
    flag = false;
  }else{
    //action2
    flag = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: Good solution, but there's already a built-in way to do this, and you don't need to manually add a counter. See my answer for the built-in solution.

Comment: @Joeytje50 True; just an alternative. Interesting, though: I didn't know about the built-in way of doing it.

Comment: neither did I, until I went looking for a way to [distinguish spacebar/enter presses and clicks on a focused button](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20849411/1256925), which is when I found `event.detail`. I've referred to `event.detail` in a whole bunch of my answers already, because so many things can be done much easier than without it. PS: if you learned something from my answer, please upvote it ;)

Comment: @Joeytje50 That's very useful. (Also, I thought I had already upvoted it; a notification from another question diverted my attention)

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the help, it worked!

However, I've put counter++ and counter-- in the if and else if statements. Which one is better>

Comment: @GeorgiB.Nikolov No problem. Good luck with the rest of your project! (Edit: it works either way, but I recommend the `++` because it makes more sense logically to count upward; however, it doesn't matter because it will just go negative and every other number is even, so you will get the same results)